A question about completetion of a ring with the given topology
I have a question about completion with respect to a topology. Here comes from two papers I read.  The link of them is Extended Baxter relations and QQ-systems for quantum affine algebras and Weyl group symmetry of q-characters. It appears in $3.5$ in the first paper and $2.3$ in the secnond paper.
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a simple Lie algebra with rank $n$. Let $I=1,\cdots,n\}$ and $\{\alpha_i\}_{i\in I}$, $\{\omega_i\}_{i\in I}$ be the simple roots and the fundamental weights.
Let $P=\oplus_{i\in I}\mathbb{Z}\omega_i$, $Q=\oplus_{i\in I}\mathbb{Z}\alpha_i$, and $Q_+=\oplus_{i\in I}\mathbb{N}\alpha_i$. We have the partial ordering on $P$
defined by $\omega< \omega^\prime$ if $\omega^\prime-\omega\in Q_+$.  Let $W$ be the Weyl group of $\mathfrak{g}$.
Consider the ring $\mathcal{Y}$ of  Laurent polynimials in variable $Y_{i,a},i\in I,a\in \mathbb{C}^*$ and let $\mathcal{M}$ be the multiplicative group of monomials in $\mathcal{Y}$.
We define a group homomorphism $\varphi:\mathcal{M}\to P$ which assigns  $m=\prod_{i\in I,a\in \mathbb{C}^*}Y_{i,a}^{u_{i,a}(m)}$ to $\varphi(m)=\sum_{i\in I,a\in\mathbb{C}^* }u_{i,a}(m)\omega_i$.
We can define a topology on the ring $\mathcal{Y}$.

We fix a element $w\in W$.
$1:$ define the partial ordering $<_w$ on $P$ by the rule
$\omega<_w\omega^\prime$ if $w(\omega) < w(\omega^\prime)$ where $<$
denotes the standard partial ordering above.
$2:$  Taking the pull-back of the partial ordering $<_w$ under
$ϕ\varphi$, we obtain a partial ordering $<_w$ on $\mathcal{M}$. I
think this is $m<m^\prime$ in $\mathcal{M}$ if
$\varphi(m)<_w\varphi(m^\prime)$. It is also
$w(\varphi(m))<w(\varphi(m^\prime))$.
$3:$ Define a topology on the ring $\mathcal{Y}$ invariant under
addition, in which the base of open neighborhoods of the zero element
of $\mathcal{Y}$ consists of the sets $U_M$, $M\in\mathcal{M}$, of all
finite linear combinations of monomials $m_i \in \mathcal{M}$
satisfying $m_i <_w M$.

Then we can define $\mathcal{Y}_w$ as the completion of $\mathcal{Y}$ with respect to this topology.
The author says $\mathcal{Y}_w$ is actually the following definition:

For $w\in W$, define the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathcal{Y}_w$ consisting of the formal series $$\sum_{m\in S}a_m\cdot m$$
where $S$ is any set  of the set $\mathcal{M}$ of monomials in $\mathcal{Y}$ such that for any $\in S$ we have $$w\cdot\varphi(m)\in \cup_{j=1,\cdots,N}\{\lambda_j-\sum_{i\in I}n_i\alpha_i\mid n_i\ge 0\}$$
for some integral weights $\lambda_j, j = 1, \cdots , N$, and for any $\lambda \in  P$, we have $$\vert \{m\in S\mid \varphi(m)=\lambda ~~and ~a_m\ne 0\}\vert<\infty.$$

Here is my question:
Maybe I can understand the given topology in the Laurent ring $\mathcal{Y}$.
In the general case, the completion of a topology group is used with Cauchy sequences.
But how can I understand that $\mathcal{Y}_w$ is the completion of $\mathcal{Y}$ with respect to this topology?
Any help and references are greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

"In the general case, the completion of a topology group is used with Cauchy sequences.", I don't think this is true, certainly one has to use nets in general, unless say, you know your topological group is metrizable

Also, there is not just one concept of Cauchy sequence or Cauchy net in a topological group, since there is multiple different uniformities on a topological group, which coincide when the group is commutative
